# How to assign different event listeners/handlers to different elements

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog

I'm working on a website that has a calendar with certain dates that are clickable. When those events are clicked, a modal box pops up with more information about the events on that day. This script shows how I'm trying to accomplish this (where the modals, their buttons, and their close buttons are stored as variables):

```
<script>
var november01_modal = document.getElementById('november01_modal');
var november01_button = document.getElementById('november01');
var november01_close = document.getElementById('november01_close');

var november08_modal = document.getElementById('november08_modal');
var november08_button = document.getElementById('november08');
var november08_close = document.getElementById('november08_close');

var modals = new Array(november01_modal, november08_modal);
var buttons = new Array(november01_button, november08_button);
var closes = new Array(november01_close, november08_close);

var flag = true;
do {
    for (i in modals) {
        closes[i].onclick = function() {
            modals[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        buttons[i].onclick = function() {
            modals[i].style.display = "block";
        }
        flag = false;
    }
} while (flag == true);
</script>
```

I thought that the `for` loop would make the right modal box pop up when its associated button is clicked, but only the `november08_modal` ever pops up, whether I click `november01` or `november08`. How do I fix this?

Comment: This is plain Javascript, not jQuery.

Comment: Oops, sorry - I've updated the tags.

Comment: Please don't include solutions in the quesion. I appreciate this has been marked as a duplicate but questions should not contain solutions/answers. This is to avoid confusion. Thank you.